# How to prevent docker-compose from killing a running .sh script?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a container that itself contains the `crontab` dependency, and schedules an import job inside the container:

`0/5 * * * * /opt/importer.sh >/proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2`

importer.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#copy files from a to b
#run another .sh script that converts them
#cleanup files
```

It's a process of about 1h.

Question: how can I prevent docker to stop the container graceful? Means, let the script that was launched by the crontab finish, and then deploy the new container with:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

Just for reference: my crontab configuration of the container looks like so:

dockerfile:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["docker- entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["cron", "-f", "-L", "2"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  my-app:
    init: true
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
exec "$@"
```

Comment: What's causing the container to stop?

Comment: `docker-compose pull` + `up`, that is when the container is redeployed (by gitlab-ci) on code changes.

Comment: When your script is running, what's the output of `docker-compose top`?